# Ubuntu Server 19.10 Raid 0 doesn't boot

Tags: boot, server, partitioning, grub2, raid

I wanted to setup a RAID0 system and when installing Ubuntu i did the following partitions:

SSD - I selected make bootable and created the /boot partition with about 25G

After that I create the RAID0 with 2 1TB HDD and created the partition /.

Everything went successfully. After reboot the PC goes directly to the bios. So for some reason isn't detecting the Ubuntu installation.

Anything I did wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Still have AHCI set in the BIOS/Firmware settings?

Comment: Yes @K7AAY. Nmath - I put 25GB on /boot to play it safe. You are right I'm not sure. I just meant is that I got no errors during the installation.